# For a site description, would it be better to use H2 or P tags?

Tags: seo, html, keywords, tags

I tend to follow this HTML structure while creating new site on my main page:

```
 <div class="header">
     <img alt="keyword" title="keyword logo" src="keyword.png" />
     <div>
         <h1>keyword</h1>
         <p><b>keyword + hierarchy keywords</b></p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see I'm using `<p><b></b></p>` to put short description of the site in it but I was wondering If maybe `h2` would be better to use here?

Comment: You probably shouldn't repeat the title in the image `alt` attribute; it's meant for text that _replaces_ the image if it can't be displayed. When in doubt, think about what the page would look like in a text-only browser like [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29). Or better yet, [test it](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/lynx/lynx_viewer.php).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Well on my current topic it is better fit to the users then to the robots(it seems spammy).On the picture it really is "my keyword logo" drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly it makes no difference. Use whatever is most logical - if the keyword is a subheading then use H2, otherwise use what you have now.

This is of course assuming that it's logical to have some keywords there. Just sticking keywords around the page looks spammy and you'll never get any links to the page.

Comment: Thats why I am asking, the keywords are appropriate here, but it seems to me like robots could find it spammy instead of gaining some weight because it is really a decription, not a subsection.Example(not a real site): title - Comedy media, desc - Comedy movies,songs..etc-